# Laptop booting to the GRUB console

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

My Ubuntu partition on my laptop causes me serious problems. I had to do a manual `fsck` multiple times. Now when I start it, it launches the GRUB console and I don't know what to do. I saw numerous Q&A here regarding this problem, but all the given solutions consist in doing a `ls` to find the partition. That's what I tried but I don't find the Ubuntu disk. I can only find the Windows disk and the partition common to Windows and Ubuntu. What should we do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

The disk is dead or dying.

Replace it as soon as possible. While you still can back up all the data first.

Just because Windows can still run does not mean the disk can be saved.